# images not appearing in chrome but they do in firefox

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox

It's the first site I put in live and I've found an issue that I can't fix!

Some images are not loading, perhaps, they come from the right path and I don't know what it's wrong.

If I play with inspect element and I take off "text-align:inital" or I change it to center, they seem to appear, but if I change it on the css nothing happen. Images still not showing.

Can anyone have a look? In firefox are fine, but not in chrome

Thank you!!

This is the link:

http://www.denison.co.uk/automotive/about/meet-the-team/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed to display them by disabling css style **max-width: 100%;**

from rule 
   img-responsive, .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img

in file bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Bootstrap is a pretty well-tested third party library; it's highly unlikely that you should need to change anything in there to make code work cross-platform. (unless the OP has been tweaking it himself, of course). If you really do need to change something from Bootstrap, then override it in your own CSS rather than editing Bootstrap itself.